# How to bypass pyplot contour function error "No contour levels were found within the data range"

Tags: python, matplotlib, exception, data-visualization, contour

For a contourless plot, `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` correctly throws the error

`UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.`

but how can I make my script bypass this error and continue running the next lines of code (whily maybe just throwing a blank plot anyway) without completely aborting the script?

Comment: This is a warning and not an error, it should not stop the execution of your code. If you want assistance, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments above, this is just a warning and your code should not stop here. If it's OK to show an empty plot in this case and you just want to [suppress the warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) you can do it as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="No contour levels were found within the data range.") 
    plt.contour([[1,1],[1,1]])
```